# OnClick for Edittext disables the default 'next' button action of keyboard

Tags: android

I have few edittext in vertical linear layout. When in focus, and I pressed next button in my keyboard, ideally focus should move to next edittext. But when I register onClickListener to edittext and override onClick method, I have observed that; pressing next key does not take focus to next(or any other) edittext.

Where as when I don't register onClickListener, focus moves when next button is pressed.

Can you explain why is this the case? Is there workaround?

Here is the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="0dp">

    <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        style="@style/TblLayout">

        <TableRow
            android:weightSum="10">
            <TextView
                style="@style/TvTblLabel"
                android:text="@string/str1" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/il1"
                style="@style/IlStyle">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et1"
                    style="@style/EditTextNumber"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:weightSum="10">
            <TextView
                style="@style/TvTblLabel"
                android:text="@string/str2" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/il2"
                style="@style/IlStyle">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et2"
                    style="@style/EditTextNumber"/>
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        </TableRow>



    </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Styles :

```
<style name="TvTblLabel" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">6.5</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <!--<item name="android:paddingBottom">3dp</item>-->
    <item name="android:paddingRight">3dp</item>

    <!-- <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>-->
    <!-- <item name="android:padding">3dip</item>-->
</style>

<style name="IlStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_weight">3.5</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
</style>

<style name="EditTextNumber" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:inputType">numberDecimal</item>
    <item name="android:selectAllOnFocus">true</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
</style>
```

Fragment code :

```
private void setup(){
et1.addTextChangedListener(new AppInputWatcher(et1));
et1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

...

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
EditText et = (EditText)v;
et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().length());
}

...

@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
..
et.removeTextChangedListener(this);
et.setText(setEtStr);
et.setSelection(et.getText().toString().length());
et.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

Comment: just encountered the same issue, can't believe you're the only one with similar issue. I believe this is a bug so I reported it: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221498&thanks=221498&ts=1472764240

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks this is a bug in Android framework. Here is a workaround you can use:

Use `setOnEditorActionListener` to listen for keyboard action button events.

Listener implementation can look like this:

```
@Override
public void onEditorAction(int actionCode) {
    // check if "next" button is pressed
    if (actionCode == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT) {
        View view = focusSearch(FOCUS_FORWARD); 
        view.requestFocus();
    }
    super.onEditorAction(actionCode);
}
```

This is what Android usually does when no click listener is set to edit text, but since it does not execute it when listener is set, you can just write it yourself :) I'm not sure if FOCUS_FORWARD or FOCUS_DOWN should be used as `focusSearch` method parameter, probably depends on your usecase. Also, you should probably add a null check for a `view` before calling `requestFocus` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You should add these to your xml file for your EditTexts:

```
android:nextFocusDown="@+id/.."  
android:nextFocusLeft="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusRight="@+id/.."    
android:nextFocusUp="@+id/.."
```

That should do the trick for you.

Comment: Thats not practical. I read about it, But default implementation should work. Trying to figure out whats the issue? Surprisingly when I remove onClickListener, it works. Thats bugging me.